# Passing bool value to start function in another page - Blazor Server

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I want to make my timer to be able to start from the button click in my **Index.razor** page too, my timer is located in **TimerPage.razor**.

I already made the button click command in my **Index.razor** page:

@page :

```
<MudTd style="background-color:#F5F5F5; width:10px" DataLabel="">
     <MudIconButton @bind-Value="@todaytask.SetTimer" OnClick="async 
        eventArgs => {await CheckTimer(todaytask); }" Icon="@Icons.Outlined.PlayCircle" 
        aria-label="check" Size="Size.Small">
     </MudIconButton>            
</MudTd>
```

@code :

```
protected async Task CheckTimer(TodayTaskModel todaytask)
{
    var result = false;

    if(todaytask.SetTimer == false)
    {
        var updateTimer = new TodayTaskModel { TaskId = todaytask.TaskId, TaskName = todaytask.TaskName, SetTimer = true };

        result = await Service.UpdateTimer(updateTimer);
    }
    else if(todaytask.SetTimer == true)
    {
        var updateTimer = new TodayTaskModel { TaskId = todaytask.TaskId, TaskName = todaytask.TaskName, SetTimer = false };

        result = await Service.UpdateTimer(updateTimer);
    }
}
```

So, It'll make the property of SetTimer to be set to true in my database, which is already doing fine : [SetTimer in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVdJH.png)

Now, I want this value to be able to start the timer in my **TimerPage.razor** . How can
I do that?

Here is my **TimerPage.razor** :

@page :

```
@page "/timer"
<MudCard Outlined="false" Style="width:150px;height:95px;background-color:#86FFB2;margin-left:390px;" Elevation="24">
    <MudCardContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h4" Style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:5px;color:#4E5450">@TimeLeft</MudText>      
    </MudCardContent>
    <MudCardActions>
       <MudIconButton  Size="Size.Small" Style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:20px" OnClick="@(async () => { Timer(); })" Color="Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Rounded.PlayCircle" />
       <MudIconButton  Size="Size.Small" Style="margin-right:5px" OnClick="@(() => { is_timerrunning = false; })" Color="Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Rounded.PauseCircle" />
       <MudIconButton  Size="Size.Small" Style="margin-right:5px" OnClick="@(() => {is_timerrunning = false; TimeLeft = new TimeSpan(0, 25, 0);})" Color="Color.Default" Icon="@Icons.Rounded.StopCircle" />    
    </MudCardActions>
</MudCard>
```

@code :

```
TimeSpan TimeLeft = new TimeSpan(0,25,0);
bool is_timerrunning = false;    


protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}



async Task Timer()
{
    is_timerrunning = true;       
    while (is_timerrunning && TimeLeft > new TimeSpan())
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        if (is_timerrunning)
        {
            TimeLeft = TimeLeft.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    }
    await AfterTime();
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

I really appreciate any help that can provide. Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship between Index and TimerPage?

Comment: For persisting data across pages, use a `Singleton` service.  OR if you don't really need to navigate, use conditional logic to swap components instead of navigating.

Comment: That's what I want to make @AbhayPrince , my timer can be used by the function in my TimerPage, but I want to start my timer in my Index page also, with the button click in my Index page

Comment: @SainBar I want to know about the hierarchy of these components, are these 2 components siblings, or parent child, who is the parent?

Comment: @AbhayPrince , So this TimerPage currently is not connected with any page in my application, I recently made this TimerPage inside my MainLayout page so it can show that Timer in any page in my application. But now I want to start this timer not only from the console that I made inside my TimerPage, but also from the button click in my Index Page

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 , Can you explain how to do this conditional logic to swap components for my situation? I'm not sure how to use it for my situation